# OpenGL GLSL texture function always returning vec4(1,1,1,1), white triangle

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, texture2d

I'm trying to work  on a texture mapping 2D to a triangle. But currently, I can only get a triangle that has a gradient colour without any texture on it. Which means, my texture function in glsl always return vec4(1,1,1,1) and my textCoords is working. How should I fix it? Any suggestions would be helpful to try!

By the way, have been working on this for 3 days.

in texture class:

constructor:

```
Texture::Texture(const std::string& fileName){

   int width, height, numComponents;
   //float* imageData = stbi_loadf(fileName.c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);
   unsigned char* imageData = stbi_load(fileName.c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);
   if(imageData == NULL){
      cerr << "Texture loading failed for "<<fileName<< endl;
   }

   glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);

   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA8,width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);


   stbi_image_free(imageData);
 }
```

Texture binding function:

```
void Texture::Bind(){
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
}
```

In my main.cpp:

```
m_shader.generateProgramObject();
m_shader.attachVertexShader( getAssetFilePath("VertexShader.vs").c_str() );
m_shader.attachFragmentShader( getAssetFilePath("FragmentShader.fs").c_str()   );
m_shader.link();

// texture created here
texture = Texture("Assets/bricks.jpg");


// enable vertex attribute indices
glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao_triangle);
glBindVertexArray(m_vao_triangle);

// Enable the attribute index location for "position" when rendering.
GLint positionAttribLocation = m_shader.getAttribLocation( "position" );
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribLocation);

GLint textCoordLocation = m_shader.getAttribLocation( "atextCoord" );
glEnableVertexAttribArray(textCoordLocation);


// Restore defaults
glBindVertexArray(0);


CHECK_GL_ERRORS;
```

uploade triangle data to buffer

```
vec3 triangleVertices[] = {
    // Construct equalaterial triangle
    vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
    vec3(0.25f, 1.0f, 0.0),
    vec3(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
};

vec2 textCoords[] = {
         vec2(1.0f, 0.0f), 
         vec2(0.25f, 1.0f), 
         vec2(0.5f, 0.0f)};



// Generate a vertex buffer object to hold the triangle's vertex data.
glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo_triangle);

//-- Upload triangle vertex data to the vertex buffer:
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo_triangle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangleVertices), triangleVertices,
        GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
CHECK_GL_ERRORS;




//====generate buffer for holding texture coordinates====
glGenBuffers(1, &m_uv_triangle);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uv_triangle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(textCoords), textCoords,
             GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Unbind the target GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, now that we are finished using it.
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

CHECK_GL_ERRORS;
```

map buffer data to shader

```
 glBindVertexArray(m_vao_triangle);

 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo_triangle);
 GLint positionAttribLocation = m_shader.getAttribLocation( "position" );
 glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);



 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uv_triangle);
 GLint textCoordLocation = m_shader.getAttribLocation( "atextCoord" );
 glVertexAttribPointer(textCoordLocation,2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);


 //-- Unbind target, and restore default values:
 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
 glBindVertexArray(0);

 CHECK_GL_ERRORS;
```

upload uniform to shader

```
    m_shader.enable();

    ...

    GLint uniformLocation_diffuse = m_shader.getUniformLocation("diffuse");
    glUniform1i(uniformLocation_diffuse, 0);
    CHECK_GL_ERRORS;

    m_shader.disable();

    CHECK_GL_ERRORS;
```

And in my draw function:

```
glBindVertexArray(m_vao_triangle);
//   below I tried, but didn't work
//   glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
//   glEnable(GL_BLEND);
//   glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
//   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

texture.Bind();
//   do these below: 
//   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
//   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.m_texture);

m_shader.enable();

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);


m_shader.disable();


// Restore defaults
glBindVertexArray(0);

CHECK_GL_ERRORS;
```

Here I will also attach my shaders
vertex shader:

```
#version 330

in vec3 position;
in vec2 atextCoord;

uniform mat4 transform;
out vec2 textCoord;

void main() {
   gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0);
   textCoord = atextCoord;
}
```

And my fragment shader:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D diffuse;

out vec4 fragColor;
in vec2 textCoord;

void main() {

   fragColor = vec4(texture(diffuse, textCoord).rgb,1.0) *    vec4(textCoord,0.0,1.0); 
   // texture(...) shows vec4(1,1,1,1)
   // radiant colour can only prove my textCoord is working
   // fragColor = texture(diffuse, textCoord);   <- only shows a default texture
}
```

[here is the running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl7PC.png)

[Here is the texture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njzzy.jpg)

Comment: Glue all your pieces together & edit in the resulting [mcve].

Comment: Hi, just tried, but didn't work. @Rabbid76

Comment: @Rabbid76, hi, my lodepng didn't show an error message when I compile it. It's strange. I also tried another function:                                                             
 unsigned char* imageData = stbi_load(fileName.c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);   this one also didn't print out any error message. But still seems like didn't successful upload image to GL_TEXTURE_2D.

Comment: @genpfault, I wanted to glue them all, but they are actually located in separate functions.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I might not sure what's real data. not null?

Comment: @Rabbid76, it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Rabbid76  Hi, I'm not sure that if you are still free. Would you mind to take a look of the case below and guess what could be based on your experience? Your discussion was very helpful to move on. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to make it work.

I copy every lines in Texture constructor and paste it to draw(), instead calling texture.Bind(). 
Looks like I make a texture just before it's ready to draw a geometry and this way is working.

But I still have to know why it happens like that. For coding style, I still have to put my code in Texture class. Would you mind to provide a solution that what happened before?

[it looks like this right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj01P.png)

Comment: Hold on. Something magic happens here. I'm freaky out. Another solution here: I change my constructor into a function called setUp(fileName).Now my constructor is empty. Instead of initialized an instance in the code above, I called texture.setUp("bricks.jpg") and texture is still there and I don't even need to call texture.Bind() in my draw???